# Internal relocation (type: OFFST_IMM) with register variables in Assembler

Tags: assembly, gnu-assembler

```
.section .init
.globl _start
_start:

@GPFSEL2
GPFSEL2_Address = 0x3F200008

GPFSEL2 .req r1

ldr r1, = GPFSEL2_Address

mov r12, #1
lsl r12, #12
@Set GPIO 24 as output
str r12, GPFSEL2
```

I am trying to use some pins for LEDs for a school task and so far it's working good but when I introduced variables to make the code more readable and understandable it all went south. Now when I try this I get this error:

```
main.s:42: Error: internal_relocation (type: OFFSET_IMM) not fixed up (on the line where I use the register variable)
```

In a colleague's project it is apparently working that way which is why I am very confused with what I'm doing wrong. Any help appreciated :)

Comment: Try `str r12, [GPFSEL2]`?

Comment: Yes that was it! Thank you so much. Could you give me some background on why I have to do it this way?

Comment: The `.req` directive establishes an alternative name for a register.  There is no instruction `str r12, r1` so I think having `str r12, GPFSEL2` confuses the assembler.